# Mariadb longtext union always return empty string

Tags: mariadb

Table structure

```
| did (`int(11)`) | data (longtext) |
-------------------------------------
|        1        | `<h1>It Works</h1>` <-- encrypted |

.

.

.
```

My query

```
SET @_did = 1;
SET @_key = 'test';
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS cnt,
        -1 AS did,
        '' AS `data`
    FROM
        GROUP_DESIGN
    WHERE
            (               
                    (@_did IS NOT NULL AND did = @_did)
                OR  (@_did IS NULL)
            )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        D_S.cnt,
        D_S.did,
        D_S.data,
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                NULL AS cnt,
                did,
                CAST(AES_DECRYPT(UNHEX(`data`), SHA2(@_key,256)) AS CHAR) AS `data`
            FROM
                GROUP_DESIGN G_D
            WHERE
                    (               
                            (@_did IS NOT NULL AND did = @_did)
                        OR  (@_did IS NULL)
                    )
            ORDER BY
                did DESC
        ) D_S;
```

### Expected Behavior

Show `data` col data.

```
| cnt | did | data|
-------------------
|  1  |  -1 | '' |
| null| 1   | <h1>It works!</h1> |
```

### Actual Behavior

```
| cnt | did | data|
-------------------
|  1  |  -1 | '' |
| null| 1   | '' |
```

`data` col always return empty string like ''. It isn't decrypt failure i checked.

If remove count query which is before `UNION ALL`;

```
SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS cnt,
        -1 AS did,
        '' AS `data`,
    FROM
        GROUP_DESIGN
    WHERE
            (               
                    (@_did IS NOT NULL AND did = @_did)
                OR  (@_did IS NULL)
            )
    UNION ALL
```

It returns `data` col ok. But with count query `data` col always return empty string.

### Env

- mariadb:10.4 (docker)

Answer (score 0):

As for `NULL` tests...

```
                (@_did IS NOT NULL AND did = @_did)
            OR  (@_did IS NULL)
```

Since `= NULL` always fails, that can be simplified to

```
                (did = @_did)
```

As for

```
UNHEX(`data`)
```

That assumes `data` is in HEX.  Perhaps you meant to use `HEX()`?  By why bother doing either?

As for

```
SHA2(@_key,256)
```

Why not simply use `@_key`?  I don't think anything is gained by mangling the key.